# Outlook for mac - Office.context.mailbox.item.body.prependAsync() does not set focus to beginning of the item body

Tags: office-js

I auto insert a signature when a new mail is composed, and then I want to place the focus/cursor to beginning of mail body, for this I use `prependAsync()` see code snippet below.

- above approach works well (sets focus at beginning) with Outlook for windows
- but the same code fails to do so, on Outlook for Mac

Code snipped used:

```
    factory.insertSign(function () { // does a Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync()
       $log.log(">> sign proccessed");
       factory.PrependData("##prepended##", function () { //does a Office.context.mailbox.item.body.prependAsync
          deferred.resolve(); 
       });
    });
```

Result on Outlook for Mac

[image]

Platform Details:

- Outlook for Mac version 15.38 (170809)
- MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Am I missing out something here. Please guide me ahead.

Answer (score 0):

How do you "auto" insert the signature? It still requires the user to click on the add-in, right?

The expected behavior for prependAsync() is that it should prepend the text *without moving the cursor*. This is the behavior that we observe in OWA and win32 desktop Outlook. We're confirming the behavior on Mac Outlook, but it is expected to be the same.

We will update API documentation to explicitly call out expected cursor behavior for this API.

Comment: Yes, by "auto insert" I mean signature (html) is inserted as soon as I manually open the add-in. For us, we are sure that `prependAsync()` does move cursor at the prepended location for win32 desktop outlook.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you were doing a setAsync then a prependAsync. 
For SetAsync -> The cursor is not guaranteed to be in the same position across different clients after calling. prependAsync -> The cursor should not move after calling.

Comment: As I said we see the cursor location getting change, and that is in fact our desired behavior from the API. if that's not the was `prependAsync()` should be used then please provide with an alternate solution if any.

Comment: Is there a reason why you perform a `body.setAsync` and then a `body.prependAsync`? Can you not achieve the same result by just calling `body.setAsync` with all the necessary data?

Comment: In our scenario.. I don't think so. It will be too much unnecessary html manipulations to do it by our self

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on the prependAsync API! Updating the behavior of the cursor for this API could be a destabilizing change for other developers using the platform. For now, we do not plan to update the cursor behavior but you can add your request to our uservoice page: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. However, with the current requests we have this isn't something we will get to in the near future.